# Схема процесса выполнения скрипта JavaScript, что корректно, что нет?

Tags: javascript

Недавно начал изучать JS. Подскажите пожалуйста, где я мыслю неправильно, а где правильно? Что упустил?
Нарисовал схему:
[image: Схема работы JS]

Comment: Навряд ли кто-то что-то поймёт из приведённой Вами схемы. Если Вы только начали изучать JS, то воспользуйтесь популярными ресурсами посвящённые этой теме. К примеру https://learn.javascript.ru

Comment: Да вроде прошёл уже этот ресурс). Просто были непонимания - если let не пишется в объект, то куда же пишется? Чуть глубже изучил Контекст Выполнения, Лексическое окружение и сделал схему - помогло уложить в голове прочитанное. Есть сомнения, что то понял неправильно.

Comment: Не уверен, что понимаю, что Вы подразумеваете под `let не пишется в объект`. Что `let`, что `var` никуда не `пишутся`, а просто объявляются в своём контексте видимости. Более подробно можно прочитать [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/let-const).